# THREE.js EffectComposer combine two scenes for postprocessing

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to render 2 scenes first as background, second transparent with HUD effects.
I want to use Bloom Effect on both.

My approach always render the last scene covering first-one:

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: 1,antialias:_basic.config.antialias}); 
    renderer.autoClear = false; //false    

    var composer = new EffectComposer( renderer );
        composer.addPass( new RenderPass( scene, camera ) );   
    
    var composerHUD = new EffectComposer( renderer );
        composerHUD.addPass( new RenderPass( sceneHUD, cameraHUD ) ); 
    
    animate() {
      ///
      composer.render();
      renderer.clearDepth();
      composerHUD.render();
    }
```

only `cameraHUD`  is rendered

First idea was to use

```
var composer = new EffectComposer( renderer );
    composer.addPass( new RenderPass( scene, camera ) );   
    composer.addPass( new RenderPass( sceneHUD, cameraHUD ) );  
    composerSpace.addPass( bloomPass );
```

but it baheve simmilar, only last scene with bloom effect is rendered

Im using transparency in both scenes and every composer rendering has transparent background, but by some reason renders only last scene is rendered.

What is a correct approach to render all scenes in order and then use effect like `composer.addPass( bloomPass );` affecting both?